# Relogin to a website in when the user is login currently

Tags: php

What will happen if a user want fill the login form again and submit it in when the user is login currently? The `login.php` is as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        //check fields and if they are exist
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        //redirect to profile.php.
        else {//the username or the password is incorrect.}
    }
    else {mysql_close($connection);}
```

Comment: Why relogin? What is not working.

Comment: @ b0s3, is created a new session id for the user? Because the  user has the session id currently.

Comment: How can I do when the user want fill the login form again, I say to him that you are login currently?

Comment: It is very difficult for me to understand your question. Do you want to check, if the user is already logged in? In this case, you can check, if $_SESSION['login_user'] is set.

Comment: I think that there is also a problem with your if-else-statement. There are two "else" blocks an one closing brace "}" is missing.

Comment: @mario.klump , can I use the **if(isset($SESSION['login_user']))** In  after the **session_start()** and beginning **login.php** file and that if the user was already logged, I can aware the user?

Comment: Yes, you can use if(isset($SESSION['login_user'])) to check, if the user is already logged in and e.g. redirect to profile.php or print a message for the user. Calling [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) again shouldn't make any problems because there will be no new session started, if there is already an active session.

Comment: I recommend to you to use `empty` instead of `isset` in this case, because it checks if login_user has a valid value. `if(!empty($_SESSION['login_user']))`

Comment: Why show the `login` option if they are already logged in? Should  they only see the option to `logout`? And an 'indicator' to show they are already logged in?